# How to find the estimated parameters in Sklearn.StackingRegressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I use RidgeCV as the final estimator to combine RadomForestRegressor and GradientBoostingRegressor and save the fitted model using pickle. How can I find the estimated parameters in the RidgeCV?

```
import sklearn.ensemble as sken

def train_stacking_model(x_train, y_train, w_train, max_depth, n_jobs):
    dict_md = [
        ('rf', sken.RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=max_depth, n_jobs=n_jobs)),
        ('gb', sken.HistGradientBoostingRegressor(max_depth=max_depth)),
    ]
    final_estimator = sklm.RidgeCV(store_cv_values=True)

    stack_md = sken.StackingRegressor(estimators=dict_md, final_estimator=final_estimator, cv=None)
    stack_md.fit(x_train, y_train, sample_weight=w_train)
    train_score = stack_md.score(x_train, y_train, w_train)
    res = {
        'md': stack_md,
        'train_score': train_score,
    }
    return res
```

I tried the following

```
md.final_estimator.coef_
AttributeError: 'RidgeCV' object has no attribute 'coef'
```

Answer (score 1):

The fitted final estimator is in the attribute `final_estimator_` (with a trailing underscore); `final_estimator` was cloned and remains unfitted.